# Removing particular items from menu and replacing the new menu through content page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I have a menu and label in my master page which i want to update depending on the type of user logged in.

Firstly am removing few MenuItems from the menu that is working fine but its not showing up in the master page. Instead the old menu is only seen with all the menu items for limited user also. When i debug the label text shows what i have set but when page loads its not updating too.

Am using the following code.

```
Label lbWelcomeMessage = new Label();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Master.FindControl("CAMenu").Visible = false;
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUsername.Text;
        string password = txtPassword.Text;
        Common common = new Common();
        DataTable tab = new DataTable();
        tab= common.GetUserDetails(userName);
        string firstName = string.Empty;
        string userPassword = string.Empty;
        string RoleID=string.Empty;

        if (tab.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            firstName = tab.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            userPassword = tab.Rows[0][4].ToString();
            RoleID = tab.Rows[0][5].ToString();
        }
        if (userPassword == password)
        {
            if (RoleID != "1")
            {
                Menu CAMenu = new Menu();
                CAMenu = (Menu)Master.FindControl("CAMenu");
                int count = CAMenu.Items.Count;

                for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    string text = CAMenu.Items[i - 1].Text;
                    CAMenu.Items.RemoveAt(i - 1);
                }

                lbWelcomeMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("lbLoginMessage");
                lbWelcomeMessage.Text = "Welcome"+" "+ firstName;
                ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).MyText = lbWelcomeMessage.Text;
                Response.Redirect("AdHocSMS.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                lbWelcomeMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("lbLoginMessage");
                lbWelcomeMessage.Text = lbWelcomeMessage.Text+" "+firstName ;
                Response.Redirect("NewTemplate.aspx");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i did is something like this

In Site.Mater:-

```
  public void CheckRole()
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Count > 0)
            {
                string firstName = string.Empty;
                // string userPassword = string.Empty;
                string RoleID = string.Empty;
                Common common = new Common();
                DataTable tab = new DataTable();
                string userName = (string)Session["UserName"];
                User user = new User(userName);
                tab = user.GetUserDetails(userName);

                if (tab.Rows.Count == 1)
                {
                    firstName = tab.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    RoleID = tab.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                }

                if (RoleID != "1")
                {
                    int count = CAMenu.Items.Count;
                    if (count == 5)
                    {
                        for (int menuCount = 3; menuCount > 0; menuCount--)
                        {
                            string text = CAMenu.Items[menuCount - 1].Text;
                            CAMenu.Items.RemoveAt(menuCount - 1);
                        }
                    }
                    lbLoginMessage.Text = "Welcome," + " " + firstName;
                    loginStatus.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lbLoginMessage.Text = "Welcome," + " " + firstName;
                    loginStatus.Visible = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Session.Abandon();
                Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.SiteMaster.CheckRole()", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

In Login.Apsx:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Master.FindControl("CAMenu").Visible = false;
            Master.FindControl("loginStatus").Visible = false;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.Login.btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
    protected void LoadMessageBox(string MessageID)
    {
        try
        {
            messages = new GUIMessages();
            popupExtend = new ModalPopupExtender();
            lbMessage = (Label)Master.FindControl("label5");
            lbMessage.Text = messages.GetGUIMessage(GUIModule.Login, MessageID);
            popupExtend = (ModalPopupExtender)Master.FindControl("popupExtender");
            popupExtend.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.Login.LoadMessageBox(string MessageID)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }

    protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string userName = txtUsername.Text;
            string password = txtPassword.Text;

            if (userName == string.Empty && password == string.Empty)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("5");
                txtUsername.Focus();


                return;
            }
            if (userName == string.Empty)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("1");
                txtUsername.Focus();
                return;
            }
            else if (password == string.Empty)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("3");

                txtPassword.Focus();
                return;
            }

            User user = new User(userName);
            DataTable tab = new DataTable();
            tab = user.GetUserDetails(userName);
            string firstName = string.Empty;
            string userPassword = string.Empty;
            string RoleID = string.Empty;
            string userID = string.Empty;
            Session["UserName"] = userName;
            if (tab.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                LoadMessageBox("6");
                txtPassword.Text = string.Empty;
                txtUsername.Text = string.Empty;
                txtUsername.Focus();
                return;
            }

            if (tab.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                userID = tab.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                firstName = tab.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                userPassword = tab.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                RoleID = tab.Rows[0][3].ToString();
                Session["UserID"] = userID;
            }
            //if (firstName != userName)
            //{
            //    LoadMessageBox("2");
            //    txtUsername.Focus();
            //    return;
            //}
            //else
            {
                if (userPassword == password)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
                }
                else
                {
                    LoadMessageBox("4");
                    txtPassword.Focus();
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new Logger().Log("ShortCom.Login.btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)", ex.Message);
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have written this code in your login.aspx. When login button is clicked then it takes you to another page and all the life cycle of page is run again. and master page contents are reset.

The solution to this problem could be. Move this logic to your master page code like

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        if (Session.Count == 0 || Session["Username"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
        CheckRole();
    }
    public void CheckRole()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Count > 0)
        {
            tab= common.GetUserDetails(Session["Username"]);
            if (tab.Rows.Count == 1)
         {
                 firstName = tab.Rows[0][2].ToString();
                 userPassword = tab.Rows[0][4].ToString();
                 RoleID = tab.Rows[0][5].ToString();
        }

           if (RoleID != "1")
            {
                 Menu CAMenu = new Menu();
                 int count = CAMenu.Items.Count;

                 for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--)
                  {
                    string text = CAMenu.Items[i - 1].Text;
                    CAMenu.Items.RemoveAt(i - 1);
                  }

    //your label logic
            lbWelcomeMessage.Text = "Welcome"+" "+ firstName;
            ((SiteMaster)Page.Master).MyText = lbWelcomeMessage.Text;
            Response.Redirect("AdHocSMS.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
    //Logic
            Response.Redirect("NewTemplate.aspx");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx", true);
    }
}
```

You have to put a UserId or Username in Session this is the one disadvantage but for every page you dont have to worry about anything.

for life cycle read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

let me know if it solves or not.

Comment: This is just going into infinite loop.. Do u think i need to make any changes?

Comment: thnx for this great answer. Its not completely working for me but i used things from your answer and now my code works well :) Thnx a ton...

Comment: i am glad it helped. If you could edit your post and post your solution after your question that would be great so other developers can take some pointers from you :)

Comment: i will do that soon. Thnx again :)